# MongoDB / Morphia saves technical id as ObjectId although it's a String in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've got two kinds of documents in my MongoDB: clients and codes. Each code refers to one client. Clients have to be stored explicitly by an administrator, therefore I have to store them separate and cannot put them into a code document.

```
code -> client
```

Now MongoDB / Morphia saves technical ids of clients as ObjectId, whereas codes refer to clients with a technical id of type String. I am able to search a code by a given client id, but at the runtime I'll get a error message, because Morphia cannot inject the client. I assume it's because of the different id types.

```
code { client.$id: String }
client { _id: ObjectId }
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Exception**

com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: The reference({ "$ref" : "clients", "$id" : "123456789abcdef" }) could not be fetched for org.example.Code.client

On the internet I found that exception message. It was suggested to use ObjectId instead of String in the model, but I have the requirement to use String. This is not my own project.

**Entities:**

```
@Entity("codes")
public class Code implements Comparable<Code> {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Reference
    private Client client;

    [...]
}

@Entity("clients")
public class Client {
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

**Storing:**

To store the objects I use `com.google.code.morphia.dao.DAO.save(T entity)`.

**Search:**

```
public class CodeRepository extends BasicDAO<Code, String> {
    [... constructor ...]

    @Override
    public Code findByCode(String type, String clientId, String code) {
        return findOne(createQuery()
                .field("type")
                .equal(type)
                .field("value")
                .equal(code)
                .field("client")
                .equal(new Key<Client>(Client.class, clientId)));
    }
}
```

Comment: While I'm not using DAOs (and therefore there's no ``findOne``), 2 quick ideas:
1) Try 0.99.1-SNAPSHOT, which fixes quite some issues in Morphia
2) Try passing an ObjectId instead of a String in clientId. At least in my DAO-less code there isn't even the option of passing a String instead of an ObjectId. Otherwise, this looks much like the code we're successfully using...

Comment: Have you replaced all @Ids with ``@Id private ObjectId id;``?

Comment: For now I switched to ObjectId, but the technical lead asked me to use Strings as soon as possible. So I'm still interested in a solution.

Comment: You shouldn't do that - see http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_do_I_need_to_change_my_@Id_field_from_String_to_ObjectId. Why would you still want to use strings instead?

Comment: It's said that they had problems when deleting documents, which were refered by ObjectId.

Comment: Works for me - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10446706/573153. IMHO something is not working correctly for you (bug / wrong usage) and now you try to compensate that by going against all recommendations. Not sure this will make matters much better ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not sure if this is solved yet. I had the same problem. The solution for me was to set the id myself.

```
@Id
private String id = new ObjectId().toString();
```

Now you can treat the id field like any other string field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I could get problems with duplicated ids, couldn't I?

Comment: Not anymore than using ObjectId() as id. I looked at the code and the id is generated by taking a timestamp, a device specific id and a static counter. For me it looks quite save to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it slightly differently so i could use the id as path param in REST requests.

```
@Id
private String id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
```