# Morphia (MongoDB) Datastore "get" returns null

Tags: mongodb, morphia

So I started working with Morphia and I'm encountering a weird problem.

Here's my entity class

```
@Entity("movies")
@Indexes(@Index(value = "Name", fields = @Field("Name")))
@Converters(LocalDateConverter.class)
public class MovieDetails implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    public String Id;
    public String Name;
    public String Description;
    public String ImageName;
    public LocalDate ReleaseDate;
    public String Director;
    public int Duration;
    public String Genres;
    public String Actors;

    public MovieDetails()
    {

    }

    public MovieDetails(String id, String name, String description, String imageName, String director, String actors, LocalDate releaseDate, String genres, int duration)
    {
        this (name, description, imageName, director, actors, releaseDate, genres, duration);
        Id = id;
    }

    public MovieDetails(String name, String description, String imageName, String director, String actors, LocalDate releaseDate, String genres, int duration)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        ImageName = imageName;
        Director = director;
        Actors = actors;
        ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        Genres = genres;
        Duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Here's my little test:

```
final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

// tell Morphia where to find your classes
// can be called multiple times with different packages or classes
morphia.mapPackage("nimrodpasha.cinema.objects");

// create the Datastore connecting to the default port on the local host
final Datastore datastore =
        morphia.createDatastore(SingleMongoClient.getInstance().getClient(),
                                Constants.DB.TICKET_DATABASE);
datastore.ensureIndexes();

    //region new movie
    MovieDetails movie = new MovieDetails("The Mask", "Stanley Ipkiss (Jim Carrey) is a bank clerk that is an incredibly nice man. Unfortunately," +
            " he is too nice for his own good and is a pushover when it comes to confrontations. After one of the worst days of his life, he finds a mask that depicts Loki, " +
            "the Norse night god of mischief. Now, when he puts it on, he becomes his inner, self: a cartoon romantic wild man. However, a small time crime boss, Dorian Tyrel (Peter Greene), " +
            "comes across this character dubbed The Mask by the media. After Ipkiss's alter ego indirectly kills his friend in crime," +
            " Tyrel now wants this green-faced goon destroyed.",
                                          "MASK.jpg", "Chuck Russell", "Jim Carrey as Stanley Ipkiss/The Mask,Cameron Diaz as Tina Carlyle,Amy Yasbeck as Peggy Brandt,Joely Fisher as Maggie", new LocalDate(1994, 2, 1), "Action,Comedy,CrimeAction,Family,Fantasy", 88);
    //endregion

// Clearing the db first
datastore.delete(datastore.createQuery(MovieDetails.class));

// Saving a new entity and getting the result saved id
String id = (String) datastore.save(movie).getId();

// This returns as null
MovieDetails movieRetrieved = datastore.get(MovieDetails.class, id);

// This returns with one item
List<MovieDetails> allMovies = datastore.createQuery(MovieDetails.class).asList();
```

When I use

> datastore.get(MovieDetails.class, id)

I get **null**

When I use:

> datastore.createQuery(MovieDetails.class).asList();

I do see my movie in the DB, with the Id used in the get function.

Tried the id in many variations... toString(), ObjectId(id), Key (The value returned from the save result).

The Id in the DB (viewed with Mongo Explorer) does show as something which isn't string (blue colored), suspicious:
[Mongo Explorer item picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARABI.png)

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
* the Id is indeed a string, the cast works and it was verified using watch + instanceof
**Edit 2:**
* Somehow the cast from ObjectId to String passed and the Id wasnt really a String.

Comment: Check what this returns and instead of casting it to string, make an object of that type.

    datastore.save(movie).getId()

It looks like it's returning null for a ClassCastException in java speak.  Is there logging you can look at or debugging you can enable?

Comment: @CalvinTaylor When adding the id to watch (without casting) the result is: "598b70468a141e56ac9e9203" and the inner value marked as char[].
id instanceof String also returns "True".

Comment: @CalvinTaylor in regard to your edit: getId() doesn't return null and/or get a ClassCastException, The id returned match the one in the DB. I've seperated the code steps before regrouping them back, only after verifying the id is returned correctly, db was updated correctly and the id is a string.

Comment: Is the _id field in MongoDB listed as type string or ObjectId?

Comment: @NicCottrell I've added a picture from MongoExplorer in Intellij. The Id does show in a blue color, which isn't usually a string (green colored with quotas)... But I did check the returned Id in many ways and it's claimed to be a string

Comment: I updated my answer - try converting your id back into an ObjectId before sending to get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **Nic Cottrell** (Thanks!) answer I've had a new perspective of the problem.
As my @Id field was not assigned by me it was automaticaly assigned in the DB as ObjectId.
As I still want to use String I've simply assigned the @Id field on object creation.

```
Id = ObjectId.get().toString();
```

found the solution on:
[MongoDB / Morphia saves technical id as ObjectId although it's a String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444786/mongodb-morphia-saves-technical-id-as-objectid-although-its-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your I'd field from String to a BSON ObjectId field which MongoDB will automagically assign on save. If you then do your get call with the ObjectId as the parameter, it should work. Using ObjectId as your ID field is highly recommended with Mongo.

I am guessing that Morphia is trying to marshall an ObjectId into your String Id field and there is a small bug somewhere. I would try calling `datastore.get(Example.class, new ObjectId(id)`).

Comment: I did use new ObjectId(id) before and It didn't work, but... now it does :/
Your solution works! 
Apparently Morphia is creating the _id as an ObjectId eventhough my String was marked as Id! either this or he simply ignores the type... the other way does work, Morphia knows to set the Id from the DB into my String.